# Get Maximum Subarray with the array

Tags: javascript

I want to do a variation of the get Maximum subarray from leetcode in which I collect the entire maximum subarray as well, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

```
var maxSubArray = function(nums) {
    let currSum = 0;
    let maxSum = -Infinity;
    let currArray = [];
    let maxArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        currSum += nums[i];

        if (Math.max(currSum, maxSum) != maxSum) {
            maxArray = currArray;
            maxSum = currSum;
            currArray.push(nums[i]);
        }
    

        maxSum = Math.max(currSum, maxSum);
    
        if (currSum < 0) {
            currSum = 0;
            currArray = []
        }
    
    }
    console.log(maxArray);

    return maxSum;
};
```

I recognize why this is wrong, as the currSum value cannot have a negative component because it'd always be a lower sum than the current maxSum. But I'm not sure what condition it would require for this. I feel like I'm missing something obvious but cannot think of it :(

```
Input: nums = [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]
Output: 6
Explanation: [4,-1,2,1] has the largest sum = 6.
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was going about it the wrong way as I was storing an array when I could have just stored the index.

```
var maxSubArray = function(nums) {
    let currSum = 0;
    let maxSum = -Infinity;
    let prevMax = -Infinity;
    let start = 0;
    let end = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        currSum += nums[i];
        
        if (nums[i] > maxSum) {
            start = i;
        }
        
        if (Math.max(currSum, maxSum) != maxSum) {
            maxSum = currSum;
            end = i;
        }
    
        if (currSum < 0) {
            currSum = 0;
            if (nums[i+1] != undefined) {
                start = i+1;
            }
        }
        
    }
    console.log(start, end);
    console.log(nums.slice(start, end+1))
    
    return maxSum;
};
```

Comment: _"I was wondering why I got a downvote"_: [StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) I didn't find a specific programming question in your question.

Comment: The code in the answer seems to be wrong. For input `[2, -3, 2, -1, 2]` it prints the max sub array `[2, -3, 2, -1, 2]` (sum = 2), but `[2, -1, 2]` is larger (sum = 3).